# grails - Video Resource not found

Tags: grails, video, resources

I want to display videos using **grails 2.3.0**, [grails resource plugin 1.2](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) and [videojs](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/setup.md). Images are accessible but not the videos. The corresponding code I wrote is :

```
 23   <video id="knowledgeVideos" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
 24       poster="${resource(dir:'images', file:'oceans-clip.png')}"
 25       data-setup="{}">
 26     <source src="${resource(dir:'videos', file:'ocean-clip.mp4')}" type='video/mp4' />
 27     <source src="${resource(dir:'videos', file:'ocean-clip.webm')}" type='video/webm' />
 28     <source src="${resource(dir:'videos', file:'ocean-clip.ogg')}" type='video/ogg' />
 29 
 30     <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
 31   </video>
```

I have videos located at `web-app/videos`

```
prayag@prayag:~/zazzercode/knowledge2coin$ ls -l web-app/videos/
total 21156
-rw-rw-r-- 1 prayag prayag  7036928 Oct  6 11:07 oceans-clip.mp4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 prayag prayag 14625011 Oct  6 11:07 oceans-clip.webm
```

I also added `/videos/*` to resources patterns in `conf/Config.groovy`

```
 36 // What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
 37 grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/videos/*','/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

The exception I get is

```
Resource not found: /videos/ocean-clip.mp4
resource.ResourceMeta Resource not found: /videos/ocean-clip.mp4
Cannot locate resource [/videos/ocean-clip.mp4]
util.ResourceMetaStore Cannot locate resource [/videos/ocean-clip.mp4]
Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: /knowledge2coin/videos/ocean-clip.mp4
resource.ResourceTagLib Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: /knowledge2coin/videos/ocean-clip.mp4
Resource not found: /videos/ocean-clip.webm
resource.ResourceMeta Resource not found: /videos/ocean-clip.webm
Cannot locate resource [/videos/ocean-clip.webm]
util.ResourceMetaStore Cannot locate resource [/videos/ocean-clip.webm]
Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: /knowledge2coin/videos/ocean-clip.webm
resource.ResourceTagLib Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: /knowledge2coin/videos/ocean-clip.webm
Resource not found: /videos/ocean-clip.ogg
resource.ResourceMeta Resource not found: /videos/ocean-clip.ogg
Cannot locate resource [/videos/ocean-clip.ogg]
util.ResourceMetaStore Cannot locate resource [/videos/ocean-clip.ogg]
Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: /knowledge2coin/videos/ocean-clip.ogg
resource.ResourceTagLib Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: /knowledge2coin/videos/ocean-clip.ogg
```

Comment: Try accessing the video from `/static/videos/ocean-clip.mp4`

Comment: @raven, don't know how i fixed it. has been a year I asked this question.